# mmap() fails when allocating large amounts of memory

Tags: c, memory-management, mmap, virtual-memory

For my program I need an array of bytes of the size of 1/8th of the processs virtual memory space.

I used the *getrlimit()* system call to get the virtual memory size, then set it to the maximum limit using *setrlimit()*. I then used *mmap()* to allocate an array the size of 1/8th of the virtual memory size. Like so:

```
struct rlimit mem_limit;
if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &mem_limit) != 0){
    return -errno;
}
mem_limit.rlim_cur = mem_limit.rlim_max;
if(setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &mem_limit) != 0){
    return -errno;
}
array_size = (mem_limit.rlim_cur)/8;
printf("memory size is %lu bytes, array size is %lu bytes\n", mem_limit.rlim_cur, array_size);
mem_array = (char*) mmap(0, array_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
if(mem_array == MAP_FAILED){
    printf("mmap failed with %d. allocation size = %lu\n", errno, g_shadow_mem_size);
    return -errno;
}
```

*mmap()* fails here with **errno 12**, which as far as I know means there's not enough memory. I don't understand why since the program barely allocates memory other than this, let alone the other 7/8th of the memory.

I tried using *malloc()*, specifying an offset for *mmap()*, using the soft limit instead of the hard limit, allocating 1/32 of the memory instead of 1/8, using **MAP_NORESERVE** in the flags - nothing works so far.
I tried running a simple test program that only does the *mmap()* and no other memory allocations and it doesn't work either.

This is what I get:

> memory size is 18446744073709551615 bytes, array size is 2305843009213693951 bytes
> mmap failed with 12. allocation size = 2305843009213693951

Comment: For an "array" you need contiguous memory, or rather you need the memory for the array mapped contiguously in virtual memory. And the system already have quite a lot of pages mapped to your process, which means it's likely not possible to map that many pages contiguously.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You should post this as an answer instead

Comment: Add a call to pause() in your main function and look at the /proc/[pid]/smaps. You will see that several virtual  memory space area are allocated but not contiguously. You have lots of holes between allocated memory areas. mmap() will only be able to allocate memory in those holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manpage of getrlimit has the following explanation.

```
RLIMIT_AS
  This is the maximum size of the process's virtual memory (address space).
```

It doesn't return the available memory size but the memory size (18EB) in the 64-bit address space.

If you need to find out the available memory size, you can use the sysinfo function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main()
{
    struct rlimit m;
    struct sysinfo s;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &m);
    printf("getrlimit rlim_cur:%ld, rlim_max:%ld\n", m.rlim_cur, m.rlim_max);
    sysinfo(&s);
    printf("sysinfo totalram:%ld, freeram:%ld, totalswap:%ld, freeswap:%ld\n", s.totalram, s.freeram, s.totalswap, s.freeswap);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Physical RAM does not limit virtual memory allocation. A process’s virtual memory does not need to be all mapped to physical memory at the same time. Available swap space might.